# Power BI: Finding the last value chosen using an Action ID (order of events) and Customer ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm currently trying to calculate in a measure the last amount chosen in a checkout process. This needs to be identified by customer ID. The last chosen amount can be identified by using the Action ID (indexes order of events, but does not reset by customer).

Three columns are Action ID, Amount Chosen, and Customer ID (see image URL below).

**EDIT 1/29/19:** The output should also exclude $0's as an output option unless the Customer ID lacks a "Confirmed". The final purpose would be to have a sum of the "Desired Output".

Example data

```
 Action ID     Amount Chosen     Customer ID    Desired Output
 1             $10               1              
 2             $15               1              $0
 3             $20               2              
 4             $25               2              $25
 5             $0                2              
 6             Confirmed         2
```

Comment: What example output are you expecting?  Please edit into your question

Comment: I edited the above - thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweaked Mike Honey's answer to address the new requirements.  I think this works - have only done mild vetting.

```
Last Amount Chosen = 
VALUE(
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        TestData[AmountChosen],
        TestData[ActionID], MAXX (
            KEEPFILTERS ( VALUES ( 'TestData'[CustomerId] ) )
            , CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'TestData'[ActionID] )
                , FILTER(TestData, TestData[AmountChosen] <> "Confirmed")
                , FILTER(TestData, TestData[AmountChosen] <> "0") 
            )
        )
    )
) *  MAXX(TestData,if(TestData[AmountChosen] = "Confirmed",1,0))
```

This is basically the same work with a few extra filters to keep the special cases ('Confirmed' and '0') out of the result.  Then we check for 'confirmed' status and get a flag value of 0 or 1.  Multiplying that flag against whatever is returned by the lookup will either zero out the result if not confirmed or pass it through unchanged if it is.

It should be noted that this measure only provides meaningful information when the information is specifically grouped at the customerID level.

[image]

Comment: No, the totaling doesn't work as well as I hoped.  It calculates the measure over the whole dataset (as it should) rather than summing the subgroups - my mistake.

Comment: To avoid breaking it out by Customer ID in the visual, can we make it a column? I tweaked it so it's all referencing numbers instead of text such as "Confirmed" (I replaced "confirmed" with 123456789). 

Desired Output = ...
, CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Action ID] )
, FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Amount Chosen] <> 123456789)
, FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Amount Chosen] <> 0)
))))

* MAXX('Table',if('Table'[Amount Chosen] = 123456789,1,0))          
 
Is there anything you can think of that could group these by Customer ID?

Comment: Changing the word 'confirmed' to the word '123456789' doesn't really fix the underlying problem - that you've made a column contain different kinds of information.  Do you see how 123456789 is really not an 'amount chosen'?     The way you would typically set up this kind of model is to have a 'CustomerConfirmation' table where you can flip a bit to identify if a customer is confirmed or not.  Relate that table through customerID and then filter accordingly.

Comment: That's good insight - I actually fixed the issue using that logic: 
***Step 1*** 
Revenue Primer = 
CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK('Table' [Amount Chosen], ""), FILTER('Table', MAX('Table' [Sequence ID])))

***Step 2*** 
Revenue = 
IF (
    HASONEFILTER ( 'Table' [Customer ID] ),
    [Revenue Primer],
    SUMX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' [Customer ID] ), [Revenue Primer] )
)

***Step 3*** 
Make a column for those who completed a transaction using a separate table (List of Customer ID's that completed a transaction). Apply a visual filter of "Completers" to visuals using the revenue measure.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of the LOOKUPVALUE and MAXX functions, e.g.

```
Last Amount Chosen =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    Table1[Amount Chosen],
    Table1[Action ID], MAXX (
        KEEPFILTERS ( VALUES ( 'Table1'[Customer ID] ) ),
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table1'[Action ID] ) )
    )
)
```

LOOKUPVALUE will pluck the value from a single row. MAXX is finding the highest Action ID for each Customer ID.

Comment: This definitely looks like it's in the right direction, but I unfortunately failed to mention a couple caveats - please see edits above